# No sound after Manjaro install, just a dummy Output

Tags: linux, laptop, audio, manjaro

This question has been asked a couple of times on this site, one for Pop OS and one for Linux mint, both fixes listed on these questions have not helped me in anyway.

I just installed Manjaro today, alongside my Windows 10 install I have noticed that I have no sound and when I go and check my sound it just says Dummy Output. I have updated all of the system packages restarted and nothing seems to fix it.

Here are the following logs.

Output of `inxi -Fazy`:

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.5.3-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.1
    clocksource: tsc avail: acpi_pm
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5-x86_64
    root=UUID=9ef59c93-facd-40b3-9731-4f2bfe49f6d1 rw quiet apparmor=1
    security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.0.4 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: Muffin v: 6.0.1 tools:
    avail: cinnamon-screensaver vt: 7 dm: LightDM v: 1.32.0 Distro: Manjaro
    base: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A514-54 v: V1.34
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: TGL model: Lily_TL v: V1.34 serial: <superuser required>
    part-nu: 0000000000000000 uuid: <superuser required> UEFI: Insyde v: 1.34
    date: 04/21/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 37.2 Wh (100.0%) condition: 37.2/47.8 Wh (77.9%)
    volts: 12.8 min: 11.2 model: LGC AP18C8K type: Li-ion serial: <filter>
    status: full cycles: 112
CPU:
  Info: model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Tiger Lake gen: core 11 level: v4 note: check built: 2020
    process: Intel 10nm family: 6 model-id: 0x8C (140) stepping: 1
    microcode: 0xB4
  Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 4 tpc: 2 threads: 8 smt: enabled cache:
    L1: 320 KiB desc: d-4x48 KiB; i-4x32 KiB L2: 5 MiB desc: 4x1.2 MiB L3: 8 MiB
    desc: 1x8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 605 high: 1254 min/max: 400/4200 scaling:
    driver: intel_pstate governor: powersave cores: 1: 400 2: 1254 3: 400 4: 649
    5: 640 6: 698 7: 400 8: 400 bogomips: 38720
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
  Vulnerabilities:
  Type: gather_data_sampling mitigation: Microcode
  Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected
  Type: mds status: Not affected
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected
  Type: mmio_stale_data status: Not affected
  Type: retbleed status: Not affected
  Type: spec_rstack_overflow status: Not affected
  Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via
    prctl
  Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
    sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Enhanced / Automatic IBRS, IBPB: conditional,
    RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: SW sequence
  Type: srbds status: Not affected
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.1
    process: Intel 10nm built: 2020-21 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: HDMI-A-1
    bus-ID: 0000:00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a49 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Chicony HD User Facing driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 1-8:4 chip-ID: 04f2:b72b
    class-ID: fe01 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting alternate: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-size: <missing: xdpyinfo>
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: BOE Display 0x081d built: 2018 res: 1920x1080
    hz: 60 dpi: 158 gamma: 1.2 size: 309x174mm (12.17x6.85") diag: 355mm (14")
    ratio: 16:9 modes: 1920x1080
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: intel iris platforms: device: 0 drv: iris
    device: 1 drv: swrast surfaceless: drv: iris x11: drv: iris
    inactive: gbm,wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.2-manjaro1.1
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
    device-ID: 8086:9a49 memory: 7.37 GiB unified: yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    alternate: snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3
    chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0401
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.3-1-MANJARO status: kernel-api with: aoss
    type: oss-emulator tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
  Server-1: JACK v: 1.9.22 status: off tools: N/A
  Server-2: PipeWire v: 1.0.3 status: off tools: pw-cli
  Server-3: PulseAudio v: 17.0 status: active with: pulseaudio-alsa
    type: plugin tools: pacat,pactl,pavucontrol
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 0000:00:14.3
    chip-ID: 8086:a0f0 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI RTL8111/8168/8411 driver: r8169 v: kernel
    port: 3000 bus-ID: 0000:01:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Info: services: NetworkManager,wpa_supplicant
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 1.1 bus-ID: 1-10:5 chip-ID: 8087:0026
    class-ID: e001
  Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 3 state: up address: see --recommends
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd
    v: 0.6 port: N/A bus-ID: 0000:00:0e.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a0b rev: class-ID: 0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 9.94 GiB (2.1%)
  SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN730
    SDBPNTY-512G-1006 size: 476.94 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B
    logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter>
    fw-rev: HPS2 temp: 35.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 141.35 GiB size: 138.07 GiB (97.68%) used: 9.89 GiB (7.2%)
    fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 maj-min: 259:5
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 100 MiB size: 96 MiB (96.00%)
    used: 55.6 MiB (58.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 maj-min: 259:1
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default) zswap: yes
    compressor: zstd max-pool: 20%
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 14.9 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4 maj-min: 259:4
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Info:
  Memory: total: 8 GiB available: 7.54 GiB used: 2.61 GiB (34.6%)
  Processes: 259 Power: uptime: 10m states: freeze,mem,disk suspend: s2idle
    avail: deep wakeups: 0 hibernate: platform avail: shutdown, reboot, suspend,
    test_resume image: 3.01 GiB services: csd-power,upowerd Init: systemd
    v: 255 default: graphical tool: systemctl
  Packages: pm: pacman pkgs: 1105 libs: 310 tools: pamac,yay pm: flatpak
    pkgs: 0 Compilers: clang: 16.0.6 gcc: 13.2.1 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.26
    running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.33
```

Output of `pacmd`:

```
### Configuration dump generated at Wed Mar  6 22:02:35 2024

load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-udev-detect
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-bluez5-discover
load-module module-dbus-protocol
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-gsettings
load-module module-default-device-restore
load-module module-always-sink
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'
load-module module-intended-roles
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
load-module module-systemd-login
load-module module-position-event-sounds
load-module module-role-cork
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply
load-module module-x11-publish display=:0 xauthority=/home/robin/.Xauthority
load-module module-x11-xsmp display=:0 xauthority=/home/robin/.Xauthority session_manager=local/coding-os:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1038,unix/coding-os:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1038
load-module module-cli-protocol-unix

set-sink-volume auto_null 0x10000
set-sink-mute auto_null no
suspend-sink auto_null yes

set-source-volume auto_null.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute auto_null.monitor no
suspend-source auto_null.monitor yes

set-default-sink auto_null
set-default-source auto_null.monitor

### EOF
```

Output of `amixer --card=0`:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]
```

What can correct this?